# Elastic Search Query String search api Issue

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to use elastic search(7.2) query string api and following is the sample url.

http://server/index/_count?q=status:active

getting below exception as "field expansion matches too many fields" with the following error. ideally column name "**status**" should go into "**fields**" attribute but it is not.

```
"query": {
    "query_string" : {
    "query" : "status:active",
    "fields": []
    }
 }
```

Please let me know if i am missing anything here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share your index mapping?

Comment: i can not share index mapping. what attribute i need to check in index mapping? is it the issue with index creation?

Comment: it might be, I need to check that, its just a mapping and if you want you can change the fields name and share it

Comment: { "dynamic_templates": [ { strings_as_keywords :{ "match_mapping_type": "string","mapping": { "type": "keyword" } } }, "properties": { "status": { "type": "keyword" }}}

Comment: what it is ?? I didn't get it

Comment: type is "keyword" for the status field